# Can't use CD /downloads

Tags: command-line, directory

Every time I try to go to this directory it says it does not exist, but it does exist!

```
~$ sudo cd /Downloads
sudo: cd: command not found
~$ cd /downloads
bash: cd: /downloads: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Try instead `cd /home/USER_NAME/Downloads`

Comment: Or if you are in `HOME` already, which is the normal case when you just opened the terminal, you can run `cd Downloads`

Comment: Notice that USER_NAME must be replaced by your current user name.

Comment: @M.Becerra next time post `cd /home/$USER/Downloads/`  $USER will be changed to current active user ;)

Comment: Didn't know that @Rinzwind , I will from now on. Sorry and thanks! :)

Comment: @M.Becerra It's even easier to use `cd ~/Downloads` or `cd $HOME/Downloads`, which are equivalent

Answer (score 1):

The right command should be:

```
cd Downloads
```

Note that the first letter is capitalized. This also applies to other directory names in `$HOME`.

```
Desktop
Documents
Downloads
Dropbox
Music    
Pictures
PlayOnLinux's virtual drives
Public
Templates
Videos
```

Comment: How come `Downloads/` is the same as `/home/USER_NAME/Downloads`?

Comment: Is the same, `Downloads` directory located on `/home/USER_NAME/`.

Comment: But that doesnt work if you are in a different directory than `$HOME`, i.e. `cd /home/USER_NAME/Desktop && cd Downloads/` shows `No such file or directory`

Comment: Still doesnt work @Liso

Comment: The command would be `cd ~/Downloads`, where `~` is substituted by the user's home directory. That should work when then folder exists.

Comment: Still doesnt work
@M.Becerra